# Display Form Field based on other Fields within the Django Form

Tags: django, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a way to only display certain fields within a django form based on the bound data of another field within that same form. I'm familiar with the idea of form.field.bound_type but I'm not sure how to continually check for state change on a field in a form and update the other field accordingly. Something like if you were filling out an application and it asked if you've committed a crime, if you click yes then a details text area pops up.

I'm using:
  Django 1.8.4
  Bootstrap3 6.6.2

As it pertains to this question. Here is what I've currently got with the field values edited for work protection. It does SORT of work. Meaning the form is fine, the if statement works initially but it doesn't reevaluate the if once the specified field has changed.

```
<form action= "/send_email/" method="post" class='col-sm-5'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_field form.field_one%}
    {% bootstrap_field form.field_two%}
    {% bootstrap_field form.field_three%}
    {% if form.field_three.bound_data == "A Value" %}
        {% bootstrap_field form.field_four%}
    {% endif %}
    {% buttons %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            {% bootstrap_icon "glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle" %} Submit
        </button>
    {% endbuttons %}
</form>
```

Solution:
With Birdie's help I was able to figure out the solution. For anyone who has hit this same Django related problem here is how you add or remove fields based on another field in the same form.

```
<script>

    // function that hides/shows field_four based upon field_three value
    function check_field_value(new_val) {
        if(new_val != 'A value') {
            // #id_field_four should be actually the id of the HTML element
            // that surrounds everything you want to hide.  Since you did
            // not post your HTML I can't finish this part for you.
            $('#field_four').removeClass('hidden');
        } else {
            $('#field_four').addClass('hidden');
        }
    }



    // this is executed once when the page loads
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // set things up so my function will be called when field_three changes
        $('#field_three').change( function() {
            check_field_value(this.value);
        });

    });

</script>
<form action= "/send_email/" method="post" class='col-sm-5'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_field form.field_one%}
    {% bootstrap_field form.field_two%}
    <div id="field_three">{% bootstrap_field form.field_three%}</div>
    <div id="field_four">{% bootstrap_field form.additional_notes %}</div>
    {% buttons %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            {% bootstrap_icon "glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle" %} Submit
        </button>
    {% endbuttons %}
</form>
```

Comment: All those pop-ups you see from other websites are implemented using ajax call to get some data, or at least using javascript to hide/show certain area in your template. Django doesn't handle any dynamic load without refreshing the page.

Comment: Shang is right.. you need to use javascript.  The reason you can't do it in the template is because the template is processed on the server, ONCE, when the page is first generated.  So your "if" will only look at the data as it was when the page was first generated.  Once the page is sent to the browser, the template is no longer involved.  So what you need to do is to add javascript 'change' handlers (probably you want to use jquery for this) to your field_three and then when that handler is triggered, check the value in the field and set field_four css to be hidden if that's what you need.

Comment: Basically you need to learn jQuery to do this kind of stuff because it all happens in the browser.

Comment: @little_birdie I figured that may be the case but wasn't sure how that would work with a unique field in a form. As I understand AJAX is event driven using things like buttons. Is there anyway you could provide a pseudo example of checking a fields bound data with AJAX without a submission event or otherwise? Thanks!

Comment: Ok let me see if I can whip up an answer for you.  But just to clear up one thing.. AJAX is when you already have a page fully loaded in the browser, and then you made an additional request to the server to fetch some extra data from the server, to use within the already loaded page.  That's AJAX.. when the browser makes extra requests to the server AFTER the page has already been loaded.  And yes it's done using Javascript.  And jQuery is a popular javascript library that makes writing certain types of javascript code easier.  Javascript is the language.  You don't need AJAX here.

Comment: Can you show us what the HTML looks like for field_three.. including any containing LI or TR tags that surround it and its label?  Then I can post an answer for you.

Comment: @little_birdie That is all in the HTML page. I'm using bootstrap3 to avoid any additional front end development. The only unique field is field four which is set to required=False inside forms.py.

Comment: Unfortunately, what you are trying to do requires at least some front end development.  The server simply can't control what happens in the browser in between when it serves the page to the user and when the user submits it back.. you need javascript code running in the browser for that.  One thing you have to understand is that the django template generates HTML.. and any HTML you paste into your template will become part of the page and will be sent to the browser.  Anyway, unfortunately you will have to learn a bit of javascript to accomplish this.  Bootstrap itself uses Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this within the template because the template is executed on the server side, but the user interaction occurs on the client side.. in the browser.  This must be done in javascript and run in the browser.

Here is an example of jQuery code which does this.  I did not test it so it may need tweaking, but this should get you in the right direction.

You will need to look at your HTML to determine the id of the element you actually want to hide() and show().  Normally you would have some kind of HTML element (eg. a DIV) surrounding both the field or fields you want to hide as well as the label(s).. and you would hide everything at once by hiding the element which contains all the fields, rather than each individual field itself.

If you add the HTML surrounding field_four to your question, I will update the answer to work with what you've got...

```
<script>
// Ideally this script (javascript code) would be in the HEAD of your page
// but if you put it at the bottom of the body (bottom of your template) that should be ok too.
// Also you need jQuery loaded but since you are using bootstrap that should
// be taken care of.  If not, you will have to deal with that.

    // function that hides/shows field_four based upon field_three value
    function check_field_value() {
        if($(this).val() == 'A Value') {
            // #id_field_four should be actually the id of the HTML element
            // that surrounds everything you want to hide.  Since you did
            // not post your HTML I can't finish this part for you.  
            $('#id_field_four').hide();
        } else {
            $('#id_field_four').show();
        }
    }

    // this is executed once when the page loads
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // set things up so my function will be called when field_three changes
        $('#id_field_three').change(check_field_value);

        // set the state based on the initial values
        check_field_value.call($('#id_field_three').get(0));
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but how would this work in the context of my example? This wouldn't check for state change. Also, does that mean I need to wrap my Django Template Tags in HTML Input Tags? Thanks for being patient I have always stuck to the back end of Django so this is pretty new to me.

Comment: It does check for state change.. the line $('#id_field_three').change(check_field_value);   registers the function check_field_value as a change event handler on the input with id="id_field_three".  Any time the user changes the value of that field in the browser, the function will be called.  This all happens in the browser.  Your template generates the html of the page, which includes this code.  When the page gets to the browser, the browser runs the code and it (hopefully) works.. without any further involvement of the server until the user is ready to submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for the contribution, but I could not get the code above work. This is my solution:

```
<script>
    function hideField() {
      check = document.getElementsByName("put your field name here")[0].value;
      response = document.getElementById("put your id here");
      if (check === "Open") {
         response.style.display = "none";
        }else{
          response.style.display = "block";
        }
      }
  </script>
```

The key is to figure out Id for the field you want to hide, and name for the field you check. I did NOT use DIV container to assign the id and the name, but inspected rendered HTML page with developer tools in the browser. Let me know if you have questions or want more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question very interesting. I have updated it with bootstrap 4.0v, with the following script, I hope it can help someone:

```
<script>

    // function that hides/shows field_four based upon field_three value
    function check_field_value(new_val) {
        if(new_val != 'A value') {
            // #id_field_four should be actually the id of the HTML element
            // that surrounds everything you want to hide.  Since you did
            // not post your HTML I can't finish this part for you.
            $('#field_four').removeClass('d-none');
        } else {
            $('#field_four').addClass('d-none');
        }
    }



    // this is executed once when the page loads
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // set things up so my function will be called when field_three changes
        $('#field_three').change( function() {
            check_field_value(this.value);
        });

    });

</script>
<form action= "/send_email/" method="post" class='col-sm-5'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_field form.field_one%}
    {% bootstrap_field form.field_two%}
    <div id="field_three">{% bootstrap_field form.field_three%}</div>
    <div id="field_four">{% bootstrap_field form.additional_notes %}</div>
    {% buttons %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            {% bootstrap_icon "glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle" %} Submit
        </button>
    {% endbuttons %}
</form>
```